# Visual Studio Code - Changing The Compiler Gives Errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, g++

When I try to change my compiler from g++ to the Microsoft c++ compiler it keeps giving me errors like

[image: this]

I have tried almost everything - I reinstalled both the compilers and the IDE but still the only compiler I can use is g++ that keeps messing my code.

The last time I was configuring my compiler was a year ago and the menu looked completely different back then, so its possible that I am not changing it from the right place. I change the compilers from

[image: here]

Comment: The MSVC (the actual binary) is called `cl.exe`. If your IDE tries to call `msvc` literally this probably won't work. Something seems to be broken or missing.

Comment: @Scheff I have checked with the developer prompt for cl.exe and it's installed properly. The IDE just doesn't seem to want to recognize different compilers than g++..

Comment: I think you have to add the cl.exe and the libs of it to your PATH variables to make VS recognize the compiler.

Comment: read the VSC doc about C++ setup carefully and follow it exactly, otherwise it won't work, there is a doc page for each different compiler g++, MS, Clang

Comment: If I remember right these start menu items for MSVC developer prompts set a lot of additional environment variables. So, if you try what @dawnb suggests this might be a good source. Though, I wouldn't pollute my environment with all that stuff if not absolutely necessary. I would start with what @ rioV8 recommended... ;-)